# How to make highchart from view table in Yii2?

Tags: php, charts, yii, highcharts, yii2

I have `view table` in phpMyAdmin.
Here is the result of my view table:

[image]

The code of my view table:

```
select DISTINCT `TahunMasuk`, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Laki-laki` from `ipbmst_orang` 
        LEFT JOIN `akdmst_mahasiswamagister1` on `ipbmst_orang`.`NIMS2Key` = convert(`akdmst_mahasiswamagister1`.`NIM` using utf8) 
        WHERE `JenisKelaminID` = 1 AND `mhsMagister`.`TahunMasuk`=`akdmst_mahasiswamagister1`.`TahunMasuk`) AS `Laki-laki`,

    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Perempuan` from `ipbmst_orang` 
    LEFT JOIN `akdmst_mahasiswamagister1` on `ipbmst_orang`.`NIMS2Key` = convert(`akdmst_mahasiswamagister1`.`NIM` using utf8) 
    WHERE `JenisKelaminID` = 2 AND `mhsMagister`.`TahunMasuk`=`akdmst_mahasiswamagister1`.`TahunMasuk`) AS `Perempuan`,


    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Lain-Lain` from `ipbmst_orang` 
    LEFT JOIN `akdmst_mahasiswamagister1` on `ipbmst_orang`.`NIMS2Key` = convert(`akdmst_mahasiswamagister1`.`NIM` using utf8) 
    WHERE `JenisKelaminID` = 5 AND `mhsMagister`.`TahunMasuk`=`akdmst_mahasiswamagister1`.`TahunMasuk`) AS `Lain-Lain`

    from `akdmst_mahasiswamagister1` AS `mhsMagister` 
    ORDER BY `mhsMagister`.`TahunMasuk`
```

Now, all I want is to make chart in Yii 2 so that the chart can be like this pic:

[image]

I want the codes in `Yii2` can take data from my view table so that when the data in view table changing, then my chart in Yii2 can change automatically. Does anyone know how to code that? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this widget [2amigos/yii2-highcharts-widget](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-highcharts-widget). Create Query for your view table [guide-db-query-builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html). Get data from it and put to widget. If you want to chart data is changed automatically you can set widget client options with this specification [highcharts.com - live-data](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data) and create specify action in your controller which will get data from table for ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer
I made codes like this

```
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Hapus;
use yii\helpers\Json;


class HighchartsController extends Controller
{
     public function actionIndex()
    {



    $row = Hapus::find()->orderBy('Year ASC')->all();


    $rows = [];
    $rowsa = [];
    $rowsaa= [];

    foreach($row as $value){
        array_push($rows,$value->Year);
        array_push($rowsa,$value->Female);
        array_push($rowsaa,$value->Male);
    }




        $data['year'] = json_encode($rows);
        $data['female'] = json_encode($rowsa);
        $data['male'] = json_encode($rowsaa);




        return $this->render('index',$data);
    }


}
```